# set UITextfield to format type

Tags: ios, swift, string, replace, uitextfield

I'm looking for a easy way where a Specific UITextfield is real-time formatted to a type. Let's say I have a textfield: taxNumber.text I want to set a type so that If the user types in the number it automatically adds a "-" after 3 numbers and stops the user from typing after 6 numbers.

Thanx! all help appreciated

Comment: Look towards [`UITextFieldDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate), specifically [`textField(shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619599-textfield) - there are copious examples available and similar questions gets asked at least once day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only thing you want to achieve is to only allow numbers in the text field with 6 maximum digits and a `-` after 3 digits, you can do the following

**Setting up your UITextField**

```
myTextField.keyboardType = .numberPad
//This will only allow numbers to be entered

myTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
//This will call "textFieldDidChange" method every time there is an edit
```

**Limiting to a maximum of 6 characters**

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    //Only return true if there are less than six characters excluding the "-"
    if textField.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "").count == 6 && string != "" {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

**Adding a `-` after 3 digits**

```
func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    var currentText = textField.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: "")
    if currentText.count >= 4 {
        //Add "-" after three characters if there are four or more characters
        currentText.insert("-", at: currentText.index(currentText.startIndex, offsetBy: 3))
    }
    textField.text = currentText
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad to be of help

Comment: Only when I'm tapping the backspace button it goes up to the separator. and I wanna be able to delete the whole number if neccecary

Comment: And I need to transform a lot of textfields is this also possible with this method?

Comment: @Stijnk008 To delete the whole number, you can set the `UITextField`'s `clearButtonMode` to `whileEditing`. This way, when the text field is being edited, it will show a `x` button to clear it out. You can also turn a setting on which will clear the text field as soon as editing begins. If you need to transform multiple text fields, you can probably subclass `UITextField` to a custom textfield

Comment: i want the user to be able to use the backspace (X) button is that also possible?

Comment: Backspace only deletes one character at a time. I suppose you could check which character was used in `shouldChangeCharactersIn` method and clear the textField accordingly but I would recommend against it